# Declaring the scalar variable?

Tags: sql

I am trying to produce a sql query based report that will allow a date range to be inserted in order to get a selection of the data available.

The problem I am having is that when I try this I get the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@DateFrom".

the sql i am using is below:

```
SELECT
  [Cost Category ID]
FROM 
   SRVS.dbo.PACostCategories
WHERE
    (@DateFrom IS NULL OR alias.myDate>= @DateFrom) AND
    (@DateTo IS NULL OR alias.MyDate < DATEADD(d, 1, @DateTo))
```

Any pointers to get me in the right direction much appreciated.

Comment: What is unclear about the error message?  It's extremely clear - you have to declare the variable before you use it.

Comment: I take it that this is MS SQL-Server?  If so, you'll need to tell it what `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo` are.

Comment: Perhaps there is some confusion over the proper syntax here? Words prefixed with an @ sign are variables, not table column or field names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare the variable before you try to run your query. You need to do the following to get this to work:

```
DECLARE @DateFrom datetime
DECLARE @DateTo datetime

SET @DateFrom = yourDateFromValue
SET @@DateTo= yourDateToValue

SELECT [Cost Category ID]
FROM  SRVS.dbo.PACostCategories
WHERE (@DateFrom IS NULL OR alias.myDate>= @DateFrom) AND
      (@DateTo IS NULL OR alias.MyDate < DATEADD(d, 1, @DateTo))
```

Answer (score 1):

The only direction and answer you need - **provide the variables to the query**.

Or you have an typo error when calling the query.